# Assigning a value to structure element out side main

Tags: c, gcc, structure, variable-assignment

I created a structure with two elements and tried to assign a value to one of the structure elements outside main function. But I'm getting error while compiling.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node{
    char a;
    int b;
};
struct node sr;
sr.b = 48;
int main(){
    printf("Value:%d",sr.b);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm assigning value after the declaration. Why is this code giving error.

error message

```
error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
```

Comment: You cannot do any assignments outside of functions. Executable code can only reside inside of functions.

Comment: Assigning as initializer like `struct node sr = { .b = 48 };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have a statement which needs runtime execution outside `main()`, i.e., in file scope. It needs to be present inside some block scope, inside a function so as to determine *when* to be executed.

You can however, use [initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_(programming)) to have the initial values stored for the members of the structure type variable. Something like

```
 struct node sr = {'Z', 1};
```

will initialize `sr.a` to `'Z'` and `sr.b` to `1`. In case you're only interested in initializing member `b`, you'll be needing [designated initializers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Designated_initializers), like

```
struct node sr = { .b = 1 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the following lines inside main() function.

```
struct node sr;
sr.b = 48;
```

Why? You cannot have a statement which needs runtime execution outside `main()`. It needs to be in the scope of a block, for example, inside a function so as to determine when to be executed.

Comment: That's true, but OP probably already knows this.

Comment: This question is looking for an *explanation*, not simply for working code.  Your answer provides no insight for the questioner, and may be deleted.  Please [edit] to explain what causes the observed symptoms.